# Can't clone a private repository from TFS

Tags: linux, git, tfs, centos, centos7

I've a problem when I try to clone a private repository from TFS.

```
git clone https://tfs.orgname.com/tfs/TFSCollection/projectname/_git/GIT_TESTRIG
username for https://tfs.orgname.com: myusername
password for https://tfs.orgname.com: mypassword
fatal: Authentication failed for https://tfs.orgname.com/tfs/TFSCollection/projectname/_git/GIT_TESTRIG
```

I'm 100% sure of my credentials and others user are the same problem (all of us have the permission to access to this repo).

Info about my configuration:

```
OS: CentOS 7
Kernel version: 3.10.0-1160.45.1.el7.x86_64
git version: 2.27.0
```

Info about my second configuration:

```
OS: CentOS 7
Kernel version: 5.14.14-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64
git version: 2.30.1
```

The TFS server has a NTLM authentication and SSH authentication disabled. I also tried to use token but fails too.
If I try to use wget (with: --user myuser --ask-password) and curl fails too.

**BUT** if I try to clone the repo from Debian, CentOS Stream or others Linux OS, with same version of git and the same user credentials I don't have any problem to clone the repo.